# If class also is class then.. move active class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement

(New at jQuery)

Trying to write a function that moves an active class along as an arrow is clicked..

**html**

```
<div id="steps">
    <a href="#1" data-ref="dynamic-tabs slider-id">
        <div class="step step-1 active">
            <div class="step-img">
                <img width="175" height="120" src="http://site.com/img.png">
            </div>
            <div class="step-title">Schedule Online or Wave Down a Biker</div>
            <div class="step-over"></div>
         </div>
      </a>

     <a href="#2" data-ref="dynamic-tabs slider-id">
         <div class="step step-2">
             <div class="step-img">
                 <img width="175" height="120" src="http://site.com/img.png">
             </div>
             <div class="step-title">We Bike to & Clean Your Car</div>
             <div class="step-over"></div>
         </div>
     </a>

     <a href="#3" data-ref="dynamic-tabs slider-id">
         <div class="step step-3">
             <div class="step-img">
                 <img width="175" height="120" src="http://site.com/img.png">
             </div>
             <div class="step-title">Come Back to a Clean Car</div>
             <div class="step-over"></div>
         </div>
     </a>
 </div>

<div class="nav-right" data-dir="next" title="Slide right">
    <a href="#">right »</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery I'm trying**

```
$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    if( $(".step-1").is('.active') ) {
      $(".step-1").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-2").addClass("active");
    }
});

$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    if( $(".step-2").is(".active") ) {
      $(".step-2").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-3").addClass("active");
    } 
});

$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    if( $(".step-3").is(".active") ) {
      $(".step-3").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-1").addClass("active");
    } 
});
```

Comment: and?  what is the problem?  why do you need three click events for the same element?  Why not just one event handler and put all the logic in it.

Comment: it doesn't do anything.. trying to get the active class on step-1 to move to step-2 when the .nav-right a is clicked and remove the active class from step-1 and so on..

Comment: not sure how to combine them yet

Comment: you know how to do an if, so the next step is to take that to the next level and make it an if/else if/else

Comment: is the way I have it laid out preventing it from working? because it's not working at all.

Comment: the most likely issue that each subsequent click event handler you define is overwriting the previous one.  So make one event handler, intead of three, and write an if/else if/else if to combine all your logic.

Comment: also, you should make sure you are defining this event handler in a document.ready() function to make the .nav-right a element is defined

Comment: Try replacing `.is('.active')` with `.hasClass('active')`

Comment: @thescientist your comments worked. If you "answer" this you will have the right one. You commented before everyone else.

Comment: @Reuben next time I'll make sure not fall asleep on the couch ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you create 3 (sic!) event handlers which fire sequentially when you click the link.

1. The first handler, as step 1 is active, sets step 2 to active.
2. The second handler, as step 2 is now active, sets step 3 to active
3. The third handler, as step 3 is now active, sets step 1 to active again.

In the end, nothing has happened.

Solution: Use only one event handler, and if-else-statements instead of only if-statements:

```
$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    if( $(".step-1").is('.active') ) {
      $(".step-1").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-2").addClass("active");
    } else if( $(".step-2").is(".active") ) {
      $(".step-2").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-3").addClass("active");
    } else if( $(".step-3").is(".active") ) {
      $(".step-3").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-1").addClass("active");
    } 
});
```

Of course, we can do much better and write a generic function, which also does not need the `step-N` classes:

```
var rotatedElements = $(".step");
$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    var cur = rotatedElements.filter(".active");
    cur.removeClass("active");
    var index = rotatedElements.index(cur) + 1;
    if (index >= rotatedElements.length)
        index = 0;
    rotatedElements.eq(index).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: +1 I was headed down this route with a generic function using index(). You had it finished before I did. Here is the jsfiddle to show your solution works: http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/LZCgY/6/

Comment: I dig the generic function! Hopefully I'll learn how to write those soon :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comment by theScientist you should use only one event handler.

```
$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    if( $(".step-1").is('.active') ) {alert('1');
      $(".step-1").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-2").addClass("active");
      return;                                 
    }
     if( $(".step-2").is(".active") ) {alert('2');
      $(".step-2").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-3").addClass("active");   return;        
    } 
      if( $(".step-3").is(".active") ) {alert('3');
      $(".step-3").removeClass("active");
      $(".step-1").addClass("active");   return;       
    } 
});
```

Comment: what does the "return;" do?

Comment: Return will simply take the control out of function..see bergi's answer's 3 points ..to prevent that i have used simply "return".

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in a single handler and about as concise as I can make it :

```
$(".nav-right a").click(function() {
    var $steps = $(".step"),
        index = $steps.filter('.active').removeClass("active").index();
    $steps.eq((index + 1) % $steps.length).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of problems here, but to address the question you could simplify your code to just this and remove the dependency on .step1, .step2, etc in case you decide to add more steps.

```
$('.nav-right').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $activeStep = $('.step.active'),
        $expectedNextStep = $activeStep.closest('a').next().find('.step'),
        $nextActiveStep = $expectedNextStep.length ? $expectedNextStep : $('.step').first();

    $activeStep.removeClass('active');
    $nextActiveStep.addClass('active');
});
```

​
However; I would highly recommend putting this in an ordered list, and not wrapping block elements in an anchor. The page will work as you have it but it's just poor semantics.